# AWS Redshift takes 4-5 seconds if I change a parameter in my where clause

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am new to Redshift and trying to get group counts on a table.

```
set enable_result_cache_for_session  to off``
```

I run the query and the second one is fast (.26s) but if I change a parameter it slows to > 4s.

I think it has to build a query plan for each new param but not sure. Is there a way to change my query so that it does not build a new query plan for change in params?

Here is my query

```
  SELECT
  LevelId as GroupedBy,
  COUNT(*) as FeasibilityCount
FROM
  Feasibilities
WHERE
  1 > 0
  AND (
    LevelId = 3
    OR LevelId = 4
    OR LevelId = 6
    OR LevelId = 1
     OR LevelId = 2
  )
  AND (CompanyRevenueRange = 2)
Group By
  GroupedBy
```

My query can have lots of different filters.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "change a parameter"? Are you changing the fields that are returned, or the contents of the `WHERE` statement (or perhaps you can show us a before/after to see what you changed)? In general, changing the "shape" of a query will cause Amazon Redshift to compile a new program that is distributed to the nodes for processing, which does add time to the query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. If I change  AND (CompanyRevenueRange = 3) where 3 is the parameter it seems to build the query plan again

Comment: There are lots of possible reasons and more info is needed to narrow down the list.  Is the table large?  Is it sorted and analyzed?  What is the distribution style and key?  What is the size of the cluster?  How many rows are there, pre-group-by, for each value of LevelId?  Is Feasibilities a table or view?  Seeing the explain plans for each would be enlightening.  More than likely RS is performing meaningfully different work for each query but why

Comment: It slows only for the first time its run like its building a query plan but its the same query just different param. Small table 27k, interleaved sort key on all the where's. Dist style all. I have not pregrouped, how would I do that?

Comment: XN HashAggregate  (cost=620.16..620.17 rows=1 width=2)
  ->  XN Seq Scan on feasibilities  (cost=0.00..618.69 rows=294 width=2)
        Filter: ((companyrevenuerange = 3) AND ((levelid = 6) OR (levelid = 3) OR (levelid = 4) OR (levelid = 5)))